# Is there a way to customize a rule in resharper similar to fxcop?

Tags: resharper, customization

I am a newbee to Resharper and found that this tool has great potential compared to any other code analysis tool.
But I was just wondering if we can integrate a custom rule DLL into resharper just as we are able to do in fxcop (apart from customizing the inbuilt options using the radio buttons)
How I should be able to integrate a custom code (rule) that is followed in my portfolio and integrate that rule into resharper? Is there a way around?

The problem is I am unable to find anything much on internet.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Regards, 
Ashish

Comment: What do you mean "integrate a compiled assembly"? Your question is not clear. You can write a plugin for ReSharper with custom inspections and actions. See http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/open_api.html for more info.

Comment: I meant a custom rule DLL (by writing a c# or vb.net code). Edited in the question as well. Thanks!

Comment: @ashishg Please give more information about what you want your custom rule to do. There may be other ways to acheive what you want or you may have to write a plugin for Resharper like Dmitry suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can write a plugin with custom rules. See [ReSharper plugin development guide](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+8+Plugin+Development) for more details of how to do it. Especially pay attention to part about [custom highlightings](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/2.04+Daemons+and+Daemon+Stages+%28R8%29), there is an example with ElementProblemAnalyzer there.